# How to add back the "loading" Element after removed it from Parent?

Tags: gwt

Ok, in `war/MyProject.html`, I have:

```
<body>
   <div id="loading">   
        <div id="waitingForLoading"></div>
            <BR/>
        <img src="../images/loading.gif" />

  </div>
...
</body>
```

in `MyProject.java`

```
public class OfflineMatching implements EntryPoint {
   @Override
   public void onModuleLoad() {
        // this code works fine
        if(DOM.getElementById("loading")!=null){

            DOM.getElementById("loading").removeFromParent();
        }


        Button myButton=new Button("Enter Main Page");
        RootPanel.get().add(myButton);
        myButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

           @Override
           public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
               // this code does not work
               if(DOM.getElementById("loading")==null){
                 DOM.appendChild(RootPanel.getBodyElement(), DOM.createElement("loading"));
               }
           }
        });
   }
}
```

So, did i do anything wrong?
Why this code does not work?

```
 // this code does not work
           if(DOM.getElementById("loading")==null){
             DOM.appendChild(RootPanel.getBodyElement(), DOM.createElement("loading"));
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DOM.createElement(String tagName)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#createElement(java.lang.String)) creates a `<tagname>` element. So, if you pass `"loading"` to it, it will create a `<loading>` element.

For a quick workaround, you can use [`RootPanel.get`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#get(java.lang.String)), and then call `setVisible` on the widget:

```
// onModuleLoad:
RootPanel.get("loading").setVisible(false);

// onClick:
RootPanel.get("loading").setVisible(true);
```

But a better approach would be creating the loading `<div>` as a widget in GWT and just call `setVisible` on its instance, without relying on ids.